# Python unicode search not giving correct answer

Tags: python, unicode, unicode-string, hindi

I am trying to search hindi words contained one line per file in file-1 and find them in lines in file-2. I have to print the line numbers with the number of words found.
This is the code:

```
import codecs

hypernyms = codecs.open("hindi_hypernym.txt", "r", "utf-8").readlines()
words = codecs.open("hypernyms_en2hi.txt", "r", "utf-8").readlines()
count_arr = []

for counter, line in enumerate(hypernyms):
    count_arr.append(0)
    for word in words:
        if line.find(word) >=0:
            count_arr[counter] +=1

for iterator, count in enumerate(count_arr):
if count>0:
    print iterator, ' ', count
```

This is finding some words, but ignoring some others
The input files are:
File-1:

```
पौधा  
वनस्पति
```

File-2:

```
वनस्पति, पेड़-पौधा  
वस्तु-भाग, वस्तु-अंग, वस्तु_भाग, वस्तु_अंग  
पादप_समूह, पेड़-पौधे, वनस्पति_समूह  
पेड़-पौधा
```

This gives output:

```
0 1  
3 1
```

Clearly, it is ignoring वनस्पति and searching for पौधा only. I have tried with other inputs as well. It only searches for one word. Any idea how to correct this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That because You don't remove the "\n" charactor at the end of lines.
So you don't search "some_pattern\n", not "some_pattern".
Use strip() function to chop them off like this:

```
import codecs

words = [word.strip() for word in codecs.open("hypernyms_en2hi.txt", "r", "utf-8")]
hypernyms = codecs.open("hindi_hypernym.txt", "r", "utf-8")
count_arr = []

for line in hypernyms:
    count_arr.append(0)
    for word in words:
        count_arr[-1] += (word in line)

for count in enumerate(count_arr):
    if count:
        print iterator, ' ', count
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is here:

```
words = codecs.open("hypernyms_en2hi.txt", "r", "utf-8").readlines()
```

`.readlines()` will leave the line break at the end, so you're not searching for पौधा, you're searching for `पौधा\n`, and you'll only match at the end of a line.  If I use `.read().split()` instead, I get

```
0   2
2   1
3   1
```

Comment: Thanks. That was the problem. I'm quite new to python.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code and you will see why that happens,because of the spaces:
in file 1 the first word is पौधा[space]....

```
for i in hypernyms:
    print "file1",i

for i in words:
    print "file2",i
```

After count_arr = [] and before for counter, line...